# Monte Carlo simulations involving mutiple probability

Tags: math, octave, simulation, probability, montecarlo

I have to create code that is supposed to display the probability of getting an ace of spades and then any 2. The main problem is that I can write code that displays the probability of getting an ace of spades and a 2 of spades, i.e 1/52 * 1/51. I cannot get 1/52 and 4/51, how do I get these probabilities?

Here is the code I have this far

```
M = 100000; %number of MC experiments to run
N = 0; %number of successful MC experiments
P = 0; %probability

figure(1); %create a new figure window
hold on; %hold all plots

%start experiment loop
for i=1:M

  deck = randperm(52)'; %generate deck of cards, 1x52 vector

  pos1 = randi(52); %select position to draw from randomly
  pos2 = randi(52); %select position to draw from randomly

  while pos2 == pos1
    pos2 = randi(52);
  endwhile

 if (deck(pos1) == 1 && deck(pos2) == 2)
    N +=1; %increment number of successful experiments

  endif

  plot(i,N/M,'r*') %plot probability of successful experiments thus far

endfor

hold off; %release all plots

P = N/M; %calculate probability
format long %prefer long format

disp('Probability of drawing Ace of Spades and a 2  is:'), disp(P)
```

Comment: 1) Matlab ~= Octave 2) "only time I will have to use octave...", that's bold, don't you think your professor had a reason for chosing Octave. 3) Why do you both randomise the deck of cards and draw randomly from this deck?  4) Would it not make better sense to label the cards 1 = AH, 2 = 2H, ..., 13 = KH, 14 = AC, 15 = 2C,... with H being hearts and C being clubs etc.. This should also make your checks easier.

Comment: Problem has been solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Originally a comment but exceeded the word count. More of a hint than an answer:

First of all, you should be clear about your encoding. What corresponds to an ace of spades? What corresponds to a 2? Exactly how does 1:52 map to the deck? I can't think of a natural encoding in which the number 1 corresponds to the ace of spades and the number 2 corresponds to a card which is a 2. A principled solution is to use quotient and remainder upon division by 4 to determine rank and suit respectively. A cheap but serviceable solution (even though it isn't very natural) is to have 1 correspond to the ace of spades and the numbers 2,3,4,5 correspond to the 4 twos (leaving the rest of the encoding unspecified).

Once you get that straight in your mind, just shuffle the deck and look at the top two cards (no reason to further randomize the selection of cards, `pos1` and `pos2` are pointless: just use 1,2). Is the top one the ace of spades under your encoding? Is the next one a 2 under your encoding?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try that

Comment: I have solved the problem. Your advice was very helpful